# Movable floating action button moves out of the screen

Tags: android, android-view

In my project, I have implemented the movable floating button but it is moving out of the screen when moved outside the corner. I want it to respect the screen bounds. Please help me with the implementation.

```
 fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        float startX;
        float startRawX;
        float distanceX;
        int lastAction;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    startRawX = event.getRawX();
                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    view.setX(event.getRawX() + startX);
                    view.setY(event.getRawY() + startX);

                    lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    distanceX = event.getRawX()-startRawX;
                    if (Math.abs(distanceX)< 10){
                    ScanQRcode();                        }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS:

                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check below class and its XML

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MovableFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final static float CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE = 10; // Often, there will be a slight, unintentional, drag when the user taps the FAB, so we need to account for this.

    private float downRawX, downRawY;
    private float dX, dY;

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();

        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            downRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            downRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            dX = view.getX() - downRawX;
            dY = view.getY() - downRawY;

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = view.getHeight();

            View viewParent = (View)view.getParent();
            int parentWidth = viewParent.getWidth();
            int parentHeight = viewParent.getHeight();

            float newX = motionEvent.getRawX() + dX;
            newX = Math.max(layoutParams.leftMargin, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the left hand side of the parent
            newX = Math.min(parentWidth - viewWidth - layoutParams.rightMargin, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the right hand side of the parent

            float newY = motionEvent.getRawY() + dY;
            newY = Math.max(layoutParams.topMargin, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the top of the parent
            newY = Math.min(parentHeight - viewHeight - layoutParams.bottomMargin, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the bottom of the parent

            view.animate()
                    .x(newX)
                    .y(newY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            float upRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            float upRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();

            float upDX = upRawX - downRawX;
            float upDY = upRawY - downRawY;

            if (Math.abs(upDX) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(upDY) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE) { // A click
                return performClick();
            }
            else { // A drag
                return true; // Consumed
            }

        }
        else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the XML of MovableFloatingActionButton

```
 <com.example.MovableFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_24dp"/>
```

Comment: Could not find 'com.example.MovableFloatingActionButton'

Comment: You have to write your package name in starting of MovableFloatingActionButton

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to there are a few steps to follow :

First of all you need to know the height and width of the workable area within which the floating button can freely move. 
To do this you can do something like this :

int screenHeight,screenWidth;

```
root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                screenHeight = root.getHeight();
                screenWidth = root.getWidth();
            }
        });
```

Here root is the parent view within which the floating button may freely move.
You can place this code within onCreate of your activity

Next you gotta calculate the radius of your floating button. This can be done something like this :

int center;

```
Rect rectf = new Rect();
        fab.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);

        int height = rectf.height();
        int width = rectf.width();

        center = width/2;
```

Voila , now you have the numbers you need . All you now need to do is set an onTouchListener on the fab button and on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE check if the center coordinate of your fab button + it's radius is equal or exceeds the screen width or negative ( if moving horizontally ) or center coordinate + it's radius exceed the screen height or negative (if moving vertically) . In either of these case just move the fab back to the left, right , top or bottom edge as applicable. eg : if the fab was being moved upwards and reached 0 x co-ordinate ( I am considering the whole screen as the movable area) then we can set the x-cordinate of the fab to fab view's width divided by 2 so that id doesn't move above the movable screen area.

Similar logic can be applied to keep the fab button from moving left, right or bottom of the parent. Good luck!